# Translation for sentence with important a grammar point: 没有。。。那么

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

This is the English sentence. I was wondering if the translation is correct. I have to use 没有。。。那么 in my sentence.

Chinese is not as difficult as people think。 Use：没有。。。那么

中文没有人们想那么难

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can just add 的 after 想.  中文没有人們想的那麼難．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel 中文没有人们想那么难 is grammatically incorrect because 想 is a verb, so we need to add a 的 afterwards.  However, 想 is also an imprecise word choice since it has connotations of "wanting" something.

I suggest the following:

> 中文没有人们**想象的**那么难。

I changed 想 (to think) to 想象 (to imagine), and you can check online it's commonly used this way.  Here, 人们想象的 refers to something along the lines of "what people imagine".

Related examples "in the wild":

> 我认为这**没有人们想象的那么**难。 ([source](https://www.coder.work/article/6924895))
> I feel this is not as difficult as people imagine.
>
> 高校腐败**没有人们想象的那么**严重。  ([source](https://www.weibo.com/1663072851/DlqO99bS0?type=comment#_rnd1603595478863))
> Corruption in university and colleges is not as serious as people imagine.
>
> 历史上的杜甫，**没有人们想象的那么**穷苦。  ([source](http://www.wenming.cn/wmzh_pd/ws/shgc/201106/t20110607_201614.shtml))
> History's Du Fu [was] not as impoverished as people imagine.
>
> 事情远**没有人们想象的那么**简单。  ([source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0017M5O42))
> [The] matter is rather not as simple as people imagine.